# JQ explode function is returning incorrect chars

Tags: utf-8, jq

I am trying to decode base64 encoded binary content in **JQ** using **explode** function.

When I run explode and then through implode, I am expecting it to return the same string. But it is not. Try it here: https://jqplay.org/s/Rt8H1qv8VRP

```
Base64 encoded string: "AQEAAAABAQAyGWRkZBXNWwcAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJClIGnj9SBp4/"
JQ: '@base64d | explode | implode | @base64'
Output: "AQEAAAABAQAyGWRkZBXvv71bBwAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKUgbvv70/Ugbvv70/"
```

Debugging further,

```
@base64d | explode | .[14]
```

returns

```
65533
```

Running the following on Ubuntu, you can see the [14] char is 315 (octal) == 215(decimal)

```
$ echo "AQEAAAABAQAyGWRkZBXNWwcAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJClIGnj9SBp4/" | base64 -d | od -bc
0000000 001 001 000 000 000 001 001 000 062 031 144 144 144 025 315 133
        001 001  \0  \0  \0 001 001  \0   2 031   d   d   d 025 315   [
0000020 007 000 000 000 000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 010 011 012 122
         \a  \0  \0  \0  \0 001 002 003 004 005 006  \a  \b  \t  \n   R
0000040 006 236 077 122 006 236 077
        006 236   ?   R 006 236   ?
0000047
```

Why is JQ returning this weird 65533 (0xFFFD) character? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the issue has nothing to do with `explode` or `implode`. Using just `@base64d | @base64` produces the same result.

jq expects the string encoded with base64 to be text encoded with UTF-8.

> If the decoded string is not UTF-8, the results are undefined.

Your input is not UTF-8.

U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER is a character used to mark input errors.